# Sorting of array with Moment(date) elements

Tags: javascript, sorting, momentjs

I have an array that is populated with moment(Date provided by the database) elements. I am trying to sort the array so that the first element is the oldest and  the last element is the newest, but with no success.

```
     for (let item of items) {

            dates.push(moment(item.created));
          }
          dates.sort(function(a,b){
            var da = new Date(a).getTime();
            var db = new Date(b).getTime();

            return da < db ? -1 : da > db ? 1 : 0
          });
    }
  console.log(dates);
```

This always prints the current time times number of elements.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's much easier than you think. :-) When you use `-` on a operands that are Moment instance, they're coerced to numbers, which are their milliseconds-since-the-Epoch value. So:

```
dates.sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

...sorts them ascending (earliest dates first), and

```
dates.sort((a, b) => b - a);
```

...sorts them descending (latest dates first).

I've happily used concise arrow functions there, since you're already using ES2015+ features in your code.

Example:

```js
let dates = [
  moment("2017-01-12"),
  moment("2018-01-12"),
  moment("2017-07-12"),
  moment("2016-07-30")
];
dates.sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(dates);

dates = [
  moment("2017-01-12"),
  moment("2018-01-12"),
  moment("2017-07-12"),
  moment("2016-07-30")
];
dates.sort((a, b) => b - a);
console.log(dates);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
The built-in Stack Snippets console shows Moment instances by calling toString, which shows is the ISO date string. But they're Moment instances (you can see that in the browser's real console).
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For some reason my console still prints the following: moment(current time value)

Comment: Like this: moment("2018-11-12T15:45:25.566"),

Comment: @JohnV - The array still has Moment instances in it, so yes, if you log the array you see moment instances. What were you expecting / do you want to see instead?

Comment: I thought I would see the sorted values. I need to be sure it is sorted now.

Comment: @JohnV - To see that regardless of the kind of console used: `console.log(dates.map(m => m.toISOString()));`

Comment: Hmm I do not get it, no matter how I display the moment element, it always returns current time :(

Comment: @JohnV - I'd look closely at what `item.created` is. I'd *expect* Moment to show NaN if it couldn't parse it (and also to log an error, if not throw an error), but for instance if you pass `moment` the value `undefined`, it creates a Moment object for the current time (as though you'd not passed it anything at all). So perhaps the property is `Created` (rather than `created`) or...? I hope you figure it out!

Comment: With typescript, I had to use `dates.sort((a: Moment, b: Moment) => b.valueOf() - a.valueOf())`

Comment: @Multicolaure - If `dates` is assigned a type correctly, you shouldn't have to put those types on `a` and `b`. But yes, you need the `valueOf` or unary `+`: `.sort((a, b) => +a - +b)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this with moment

```
dates.sort((a, b) => moment(a.date) - moment(b.date))
```