# TypeError: moment__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default(...)(...).calendar(...).sort is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, mapping

I fetch the data from [this link](http://open-api.myhelsinki.fi/v1/events/?distance_filter=60.1699%2C24.9384%2C5&language_filter=en&limit=50&start=1).

I want to show the data based on a recent date. I used the map method to render the data then try to use sort them based on date. But I got an error. I used the moment package to making the date organized. Sorry for my English, I don't know if express my feeling right.

**This is my React's component setup**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import moment from "moment";


const Events = () => {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchingData();
  }, []);

  const fetchingData = () => {
    axios
      .get("/events")
      .then(response => {
        console.log("response", response);
        setEvents(response.data.data);
      }) 
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  //do console.log
  console.log("events", events);

  return (
    <div>
      {events.map(list => {
        return (
          <div>
            <div className="card">
              <div className="carddd">
                <div className="card_image">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      {moment(list.event_dates.starting_day.toString())
                        .calendar()
                        .sort((a, b) => { // I try sort date in here.
                          return a - b;
                        })}
                    </li>
                  </ul>

                  <div>
                    {list.description.images.map(img => {
                      return (
                        <img
                          src={img.url}
                          alt="jj"
                          style={{ width: "250px", height: "250px" }}
                        />
                      );
                    })}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Events;
```

**Screenshot below**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by Moment's documentation on `.calendar()` here it returns a string:
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/

Javascript strings do not have a .sort() function, so you're trying to call a function that doesn't exist which is causing your error.

You will want to sort the dates before converting them to strings, so you'll want to run sort on your `events` array before you do the map.

**Solution edit:**

So your response comes back and you have the events in state under `events`.

Before you render, you could [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) your events data down to just being dates, keyed using the ID of each event.

```
const eventDates = events.reduce((acc, event) => {
    acc[event.id] = {
        startDate: moment(event.event_dates.starting_day),
        endDate: moment(event.event_dates.ending_day),
        // You could also add more info in here, like the name or location.
    }
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Then use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array (which can be sorted, objects can't.) of the keys. Then sort that array by accessing the values in eventDates, using the keys in the array, like so.

```
let sortedByStartDate = Object.keys(eventDates);
sortedByStartDate.sort(
    (a, b) => eventDates[a].startDate - eventDates[b].startDate
);
```

The keys will now be sorted by the start dates. ([By the way, to sort moment objects, you can just use the - operator on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53264492/sorting-of-array-with-momentdate-elements)).

Now when you are rendering you want to map through the `sortedByStartDate` array, using the keys to access values in `eventDates` (you may also want to add additional information in here in the reduce to get access to, instead of just dates).

```
sortedByStartDate.map(
    eventKey => <li>{eventDates[eventKey].startDate.calendar()}</li>
);
```

Comment: Really good point @William. But the problem is if you check the link which I posted, their date query looks like this: `"starting_day": "2020-01-26T22:01:00.000Z"`. I don't know how to sort that data.

Comment: @dam I've updated my answer with a way you can solve this. I'd recommend visiting the links that I've provided throughout to understand fully what is happening. The general idea is to transform the data into how you need it before you try render it.

Comment: Another problem just arises :). How can I render my images, name other queries :D from that API

Comment: @dam Like the comment in my code describes, you'd bring those into the reduced object (currently eventDates, but obviously re-name this if it includes more than just dates), then use the same method as rendering the date to pull the data out of that object.

Comment: I have tried mate @William, But something I am doing wrong. 

I accumulate the data like this:

`const eventDates = events.data.reduce((acc, event) => {
    acc[event.id] = {
      startDate: moment(event.event_dates.starting_day),
      endDate: moment(event.event_dates.ending_day),
      image: event.description.images
    };
    return acc;
  }, {});
  console.log(eventDates);`

Comment: Trying to render it like this:

`<div>
      {sortedByStartDate.map(list => {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>{eventDates[list].startDate.calendar()}</h1>
            <div>
              {eventDates[list].image(img => {
                return <img src={img.url} alt="kk" />;
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>`

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted :)